# Cannot import solution from PowerApps to CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamics-365

I need to export a solution from PowerApps (model driven), version 9.2
and import it to CRM, version 9.1.

I have an error because of this version. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the solution for a previous target version.
In .NET/C# you can do this using the `ExportSolutionRequest`:

```cs
public string ExportSolution(string solutionName, bool asManaged)
{
    var request = new ExportSolutionRequest
    {
        SolutionName = solutionName,
        Managed = asManaged,
        TargetVersion = "9.1"
    };

    var response = _service.Execute(request) as ExportSolutionResponse;

    string solutionZipPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
    File.WriteAllBytes(solutionZipPath, response.ExportSolutionFile);

    return solutionZipPath;
}
```

In the example above `_service` is of type `IOrganizationService`.

Another solution would involve a tweak:

- Export the solution.
- Extract the solution zip.
- Open the solution.xml manifest in a text editor.
- In the root `ImportExportXml` element change the value of attribute `SolutionPackageVersion` into the desired version.
- Save your changes.
- Zip the solution.
- Import the modified solution in the target environment.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImportExportXml version="9.2.21082.140" SolutionPackageVersion="9.2" languagecode="1033" generatedBy="CrmLive" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SolutionManifest>
...
  </SolutionManifest>
</ImportExportXml>
```

Last approach does not guarantee the solution can be imported without issues as it can contain features not supported by a previous version. However, sometimes it is possible to remove these features by hand.